# 403: Forbidden when trying to update item properties with SharePoint API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems, .net

In my .NET Core API I'm trying to update a document library item property with the SharePoint API. I already succeeded to get the document library item by id and by filter. When I try to update an item property, it returns a 403: Forbidden status with the message

**The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.**

Although the user that I use to authenticate to SharePoint has full access.

The code that I'm using, can be found below. I've tried to change the request headers in every combination. For the X-HTTP-METHOD, MERGE or PUT, for IF-MATCH * or the version I got by the GET call, ...

```
 var url = "https://sharepointsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Document Signage\')/items(164)";

        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialsCache.Add(uri, "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain));
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, httpClient.BaseAddress);
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var listItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharePointListItemProperties>(result);

            string formDigestValue = await GetFormDigestValue();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("IF-MATCH", "5");
            var httpUpdateRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, httpClient.BaseAddress);
            httpUpdateRequest.Content = new StringContent("{\'__metadata\': { \'type\': \'SP.Data.Document SignageItem\' }, \'Status1\': \'Completed\'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage respUpd = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpUpdateRequest);
            string result2 = respUpd.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

I've read that most of the cases where in javascript, but as said, because I call it from an API it's in C#.

Does anyone has a possible solution?

Comment: I have not worked with .net core api, but in javascript you  get this error when your FormDigestValue is null.

Answer (score 0):

In some posts I read to just take the first part of the FormDigestValue. After putting it completely in the header, adding the content header to "application/json;odata=verbose" and changing the IF-MATCH header to *.

`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
 var httpUpdateRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, httpClient.BaseAddress);
 httpUpdateRequest.Content = new StringContent("{\'__metadata\': { \'type\': \'SP.Data.Document_x0020_SignageItem\' }, \'Status1\': \'Sent\'}");
 httpUpdateRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");`